# How to use GCP projects that we're billed for but can't access

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm a billing administrator for several GCP projects. Some of them I can't access so I can't tell if they're still required. They have very low usage e.g. $0.25 / month so probably just storage costs. I'm pretty sure they were created by a sysadmin who used to work here but has left and he doesn't seem to have given anyone else rights to view the project.

Is there any way to get myself added as a project owner since we're paying for it?

Comment: As far as I know, only the project owners can add others to become project owners.

Comment: You'll need to be the project owner in order to change ownership of the project. You'll need to [contact support](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7283495?hl=en&ref_topic=7282190) as stated on relevant section of the documentation.

Comment: @DanielOcando thanks, I guessed that was going to be the case. Good to have it confirmed. Dunno if you can make your comment and answer, but I'd happily accept that for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to be the project owner in order to change ownership of the project. You'll need to [contact support](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7283495?hl=en&ref_topic=7282190) as stated on relevant section of the documentation.